# KeyError: "None of [Index(['Patient number',] python

Tags: python, dataset

```
#import excel 
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/data/dataset MS.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(path)
X=df[['Patient number','Gender','Age (years)','Other']].values
Y=df['Pationt'].values
model.fit(X,Y)
y_pred=model.pridict(X)
```

when i run the code i have error:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 2 path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Graduation_Project_I/data/dataset MS.xlsx'
> 3 df=pd.read_excel(path)
> ----> 4 X=df[['Patient number','Gender','Age (years)',  'Other']].values
> 5 Y=df['Pationt'].values
> 6 model.fit(X,Y)
>
> 2 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in
> _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)    1372                 if use_interval_msg:    1373                     key = list(key)
> -> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")    1375     1376             not_found =
> list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
>
> KeyError: "None of [Index(['Patient number', 'Gender', 'Age (years)',
> 'Other'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

what should i do?

Comment: Try printing the column names of your loaded excel first. In the line right after `df=...`: `print(df.columns)`

Comment: Make sure the columns exist...